# multiple methods try without skipping others php

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have this code:

```
try{
  firstMethod()
  secondMethod()
}
catch(Exception $e){
  ....
}
```

What I want is execute all `try/catch`  block functions but capturing if one throws exception, without skipping the following methods
a possible but not pretty code would be:

```
try{
  firstMethod();
}
catch(Exception $e){
  ....
}
try{
  secondMethod();
}
catch(Exception $e){
  ....
}
```

Comment: cant understand. What is your question here?

Comment: try{ firstMethod(); secondMethod();} catch(Exception $e){} ... whats wrong in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you might have *a lot* of those if you are looking for more convenient way than "not pretty" take?

I would say just loop through them:

```php
foreach ( [ 'firstMethod', 'secondMethod' ] as $callable ) {
    try {
        $callable();
    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice. I didn't think of this. It will be problematic if the methods require different variables, but otherwise, very nice.

Comment: This can be respectively scaled for more complex use cases, for example you can have a factory to produce closure callbacks for the set.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write try catch in each function and log the exceptions somewhere.

```
function firstMethod() {
    try {
        //code
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        logException($e);
    }
}

function secondMethod() {
    try {
        //code
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        logException($e);
    }
}

function mainMethod() {
    firstMethod();
    secondMethod();
}
```

This will help in doing something like this:

```
function someOtherMethod() {
    secondMethod();
}
```